# How to get url param in middleware go-chi

Tags: go, url, parameters, middleware, go-chi

I use a specific middleware for specific set of routes

```
r.Route("/platform", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(authService.AuthMiddleware)
    r.Get("/{id}/latest", RequestPlatformVersion)
})
```

Now how can I access `id` url param inside this `AuthMiddleware` middleware

```
func (s *Service) AuthMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(chi.URLParam(r, "id"))
        id := chi.URLParam(r, "id")
        
        if id > 100 {
          http.Error(w, errors.New("Error").Error(), http.StatusUnauthorized)
          return
        }
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

However, the id param prints as an empty string even though the middleware is being ran and a specific route is being called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put your `chi.URLParam` before the path param `{id}` and you forgot to put `.ServeHTTP(w, r)` at the middleware. If you don't put that thing, your request will not go inside the path inside the route.

this is the working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

func AuthMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(chi.URLParam(r, "id"))
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Route("/platform/{id}", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(AuthMiddleware)
        r.Get("/latest", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Println("here ", chi.URLParam(r, "id")) // <- here
        })
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

I move the `{id}` to `platform/{id}` so the middleware got the `id` path value, and add `h.ServeHTTP(w, r)` inside the middleware.

try to access `http://localhost:8080/platform/1/latest`

the output will be:

```
1
here  1
```

UPDATE

It is not good to run the validation after the code, you must fix the way you define the path, and move the `.ServeHTTP` after the validation.

This is the example:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

func AuthMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Printf("Middleware First, id: %+v\n", chi.URLParam(r, "id"))
        id, _ := strconv.Atoi(chi.URLParam(r, "id"))

        if id > 100 {
            http.Error(w, errors.New("Error").Error(), http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    // This works too ()
    // r.Route("/platform/{id}", func(r chi.Router) {
    //  r.Use(AuthMiddleware)
    //  r.Get("/latest", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //      fmt.Println("second: ", chi.URLParam(r, "id")) // <- here
    //  })
    // })

    // Other Solution (Wrapping Middleware)
    r.Route("/platform", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Get("/{id}/latest", AuthMiddleware(http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Println("second: ", chi.URLParam(r, "id")) // <- here
        })).ServeHTTP)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

Comment: I had used ``h.ServeHTTP(w, r)`` inside the middleware. But it's only after trying to retrieve url parameters. So, that's why it didn't work. So, the answer should be also using ``h.ServeHTTP(w, r)`` before the ``fmt.Println(chi.URLParam(r, "id"))`` no ?

Comment: yes, that one will works.

Comment: Thanks. But this always returns success, right ?
I updated the code block in question, there I need to check the id conditionally and return an error. So, that can't be done, in this case, can it ?

Comment: no that can't be done if you write your h.ServeHTTP the `id` check. It is not a good thing, to run the code first then check for validation. To work around it, I have other solution, wrap your `RequestPlatformVersion` with your middleware in the  `r.Get` instead of `r.Use` (see the UPDATE part), or you can just update your route to `r.Route("/platform/{id}", ...)` so you can include the middleware, and `h.ServeHTTP()` after the validation

Comment: The reason I tried to use middleware was the check should go through for all the paths in ``/platform/{id}`` . But running that validation inside each routes means, I have to add the same logic in multiple routes, no ?

Comment: yes, middleware validation inside r.Route(), apply to all route inside r.Route(), if you want to have different validation value validation for each route, I think you can validate it manually inside each route.

Personally, I like to use gin Framework instead of Chi, because of validation feature from it.
example: https://pastebin.com/0fYZLB35
under the hood of the validation, gin use https://github.com/go-playground/validator

Comment: Thank you. I ended up adding the validation separately for each route rather than a middleware as you mentioned. Switching from chi to gin is not possible since what I'm working on now is already created api, which I'm adding some features.

Comment: @ThidasaPankaja you can also use chi's Group function to apply the same middleware to a set of routes